# Trying to display Custom View in MVC app but it says requested URL not found

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I am new to azure, MVC and also ASP.NET. I am writing MVC Cloud service with ASP.NET web role. Please help me with this problem

When I create the application there are default views but I wanted to see my view so I set my view as start page. I also changed the values in RegisterRoutes method

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "AddUser", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
 }
```

When I run the app, it gives HTTP 404 error because it could not find request URL : /Views/User/AddUser.cshtml

[image]

Comment: it seems that you are trying to access the view directly from the URL. In MVC, your request should be targetting to a controller action, and not a view directly. So in a case like this, check what happens when you try to access a URL - ....\User\AddUser

Comment: You access a view by navigating to a method in a controller which returns the view. Suggest you go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials to learn the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MVC you don't put the view in the URL to get it rendered.

This won't work: `/Views/User/AddUser.cshtml`

As you've correctly put in your question the default route is `{controller}/{action}/{id}` with `id` being optional.

So assuming that **User** is your controller, i.e. you have a class called `UserController`, which looks something like:

```
namespace My.Controllers
{
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
```

which has an action on it called **AddUser**:

```
        public ActionResult AddUser()
        { 
          // implementation logic
          return View();
        }
```

Then the default route will display your view when it processes the URL **/User/AddUser**

In MVC 5, this looks something like:

[image: example]

Comment: I was exactly what you mentioned. I don't know what was going wrong. I re-created the project and did exactly the same thing and it displays the view I created. Thank you very much

Comment: @Fairy glad you got it sorted. Don't forget to mark this as the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) :-)